# Trying to allow for a range of numbers (0.0 - 4.0) for a GPA program

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to check for a number between 0.0 and 4.0 using filter_var in PHP. When I run the site I can get all the forms to work besides the ones that deal with numbers. Specifically, I am stuck on the "current_gpa check". I don't understand what I've done wrong as it will accept anything now. I've tried changing my comparison and that didn't help. Any help would be great.

```
// Current GPA Check
        if (!empty($_POST['current_gpa']) && (filter_var($_POST['current_gpa'], FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT) === false) || ($_POST['current_gpa'] > 4.0) || ($_POST['current_gpa'] < 0.0))
        {
            $current_gpa_error = "* Your current GPA must be between 0.0 and 4.0";
        }
        else 
        {
            $current_gpa = $_POST['current_gpa'];
        }
```

This is current.

I will attach the rest of my code for reference.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<title>GPA Improvement Calculator</title>
<style>
    .error {
      color: #FF0000;
    }
  </style>
  </head>

  <body>
  <h1>GPA Improvement Calculator</h1>

  <p><span class="error">All form fields must be completed for the GPA calculator to function. 
  </span></p>

<?php 
    function sanitizeString($var)
    {
        $var = stripslashes($var);
        $var = strip_tags($var);
        $var = htmlentities($var);
        return $var;
    }

    $name = "";
    $email = "";
    $agree = "";
    $current_gpa = "";
    $current_total_creds = "";
    $current_credits = "";
    $desired_gpa = "";

    $name_error = "";
    $email_error = "";
    $agree_error = "";
    $current_gpa_error = "";
    $current_total_creds_error = "";
    $current_credits_error = "";
    $desired_gpa_error = "";

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
        // Name Check
        if (!empty($_POST['name']) && preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/', $_POST['name']))
        {
            $name = $_POST['name'];
        }
        else {
            $name_error = "* Your name must contain letters and white space";
        }


        // Email Check
        if (!empty($_POST['email']) && filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
        {
            $email = $_POST['email'];
        }
        else {
            $email_error = "* Invalid email format";
        }


        // Agreement Check
        if (empty($_POST['agree']))
        {
            $agree_error = "* You must agree to the terms and conditions";
        }


        // Current GPA Check
        if (!empty($_POST['current_gpa']) && (filter_var($_POST['current_gpa'], FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT) === false) || ($_POST['current_gpa'] > 4.0) || ($_POST['current_gpa'] < 0.0))
        {
            $current_gpa_error = "* Your current GPA must be between 0.0 and 4.0";
        }
        else 
        {
            $current_gpa = $_POST['current_gpa'];
        }

        // Current Total Credits Check
        if (!empty($_POST['current_total_creds']) && preg_match('/^[0-9,]*$/', $_POST['current_total_creds']))
        {
            $current_total_creds = $_POST['current_total_creds'];
        }
        else
        {

            $current_total_creds_error = "* Your current number of credits must be a positive integer";
        }


        // Current Semester Credits Check
        if (empty($_POST['current_credits']))
        {
            $current_credits_error = "* (the number of credits this semester as an integer greater than 0";
        }
        else {
            $current_credits = sanitizeString($_POST['current_credits']);
        }


        // Desired GPA Check
        if (empty($_POST['desired_gpa']))
        {
            $desired_gpa_error = "* (your desired GPA increase must be a positive value)";
        }
        else {
            $desired_gpa = sanitizeString($_POST['desired_gpa']);
        }
    }
?>

<form method="post" action="improveGPA.php">

    Name: <input type="text" size="35" name="name" value="">
    <span class="error"><?php echo $name_error; ?></span>
    <br><br>

    E-mail: <input type="text" size="35" name="email" value="">
    <span class="error"><?php echo $email_error; ?></span>
    <br><br>

    <input type="checkbox" name="agree"  >
    I agree to the terms and conditions of this website.
    <span class="error"><?php echo $agree_error; ?></span>
    <br><br>

    Current GPA: <input type="text" size="4" name="currentGPA" value="">
    <span class="error"><?php echo $current_gpa_error; ?></span>
    <br><br>

    Current Total Credits: <input type="text" size="3" name="currentCredits" value="">
    <span class="error"><?php echo $current_total_creds_error; ?></span>
    <br><br>

    I am taking <input type="text" size="3" name="newCredits" value="">
    <span class="error"><?php echo $current_credits_error; ?></span> credits this semester.

    If I want to raise my GPA
    <input type="text" size="4" name="GPAincrease" value="">
    <span class="error"><?php echo $desired_gpa_error; ?></span> points,
    I need a <span style="font-weight: bold;">????</span> GPA on my courses this semester.
    <br><br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Calculate">

</form>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `name="currentGPA" != name="current_gpa"` you named your input incorrectly. `Current GPA: <input type="text" size="4" name="currentGPA" value="">`

Comment: @bassxzero , you are a life-saver. Thanks!